# Order of Bootstrap and Js references in ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Now I have updated the references and found that error in image.

Some of these files are not working, please guide me about the order of bootstrap and js files to work. Because some of my code is not working because of wrong order of references. For more information, see the image below

```
1.<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
2.<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
3.<link href="~/Content/AdminBootStrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
4.<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
5.<link href="~/Content/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />  <!-- CSS reset -->
6.<link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- Resource style -->
7.<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
8.<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--End Bootstrap-->
<!--Start Scripts-->
9.<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
10.<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJavaScript.js"></script>
11.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
12.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
13.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
14.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
15.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
16.<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
17<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
18.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
19.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
20.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
21.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
22.<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
23.<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
24.<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
25.<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
26.<script src="~/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
27.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
28.<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script> <!-- menu aim -->
29.<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>  <!-- Resource jQuery -->
30<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
<!--End Scripts-->
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading 5 different instances of jQuery.js when all you need is one.

Also any plugins or code that depend on jQuery must load after jQuery does...that includes `bootstrap.js`

You are also loading duplicates for all the other scripts. A `.min` version is the same script as a full version but is minified for smaller file size.

This could be scaled down to

```
<!--Start Scripts-->
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>

<!--End Scripts-->
<!--Start: Subject Dropdown-->

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script> <!-- menu aim -->
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>  <!-- Resource jQuery -->
```

Comment: If any of this order causes errors to be thrown adjustments may still need to be made regarding order since I don't know what some of them are like `CustomJavaScript` or `_references`

Comment: why you put    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> instead of     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script> . May I know the reason please

Comment: depends on browsers you want to support

Answer (score 1):

It would be exceedingly helpful if you actually posted your BundleConfig.cs file, as that determines entirely what happens here. However, some general advice:

The order of individual files in a bundle is *not* guaranteed. The default is to order alphabetically by filename. This usually covers most scenarios as the sub-components are generally named after the main library they utilize. For example, if you had a `Foo` plugin that utilized jquery, it would normally be named something like `jquery.foo.js`. Alphabetically, then, the main jQuery library would be called first, before the plugin.

If you're referencing multiple unrelated scripts in a single bundle, then all of those scripts should be order-independent, i.e. they shouldn't depend on each other. If you need to ensure that something like jQuery is loaded before something like Bootstrap.js, that utilizes jQuery, they should be in *different* bundles, and then you can ensure the order by how you call them, i.e.:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")
```

This is usually a good idea, anyways, as often things like jQuery should be loaded from a CDN, which means it must be its own bundle, anyways.

If you truly do need to ensure the order of the scripts within a bundle, then you must use a custom bundle orderer:

```
class NonOrderingBundleOrderer : IBundleOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        return files;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var myAwesomeBundle = new Bundle(...).Include(...);
myAwesomeBundle.Orderer = new NonOrderingBundleOrderer();
bundles.Add(myAwesomeBundle);
```

That particular implementation of `IBundleOrderer` simply renders the scripts, as-is, in the order you put them in the `Include` call. That way you can ensure that the order is exactly how you want.

Comment: In my ASP.NET MVC5 Project, there is no bundle option. I just put all these references in a partial view and put it a header

Comment: By the way, thanks for your response, your provided info is useful to me :-)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is then. JavaScript is run serial and blocking, so the order that the actual script tags exist on the page is the order they are loading. The only exception would be if you were using something like the `async` or `defer` attributes in a supported browser, but you're not doing that, based on the code  you've posted.